# How can I reduce memory used by WebCameraTexture in unity on windows phone?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, windows-phone

I made a demo application with two simple view in unity3d for windows phone platform.On first view I have a button and a text, from inspector I assign to button one event ( on Click) to open second view. In this view I have a raw image in a panel used to assign mainTexture to webCamTexture for to Start camera on phone.

```
var webCamTexture = new WebCamTexture();
rawImage.material.mainTexture = webCamTexture;
webCamTexture.Play();
```

In second View I have a button where I close camera and show first view ( closing current) `webCameraTexture.Stop();`

If I do that many times Play() and Stop() memory on my phone looks like:

[image]

How can I clear memory, when I stop the camera, because sometimes give me an error "Not enought storage to complete this operation" and exit from application.

Code Start Stop Camera:

```
    //call onClick Button (next)
    public void StartMyCamera()
    {
        webCamTexture = new WebCamTexture();
        rawImage.material.mainTexture = webCamTexture;
        webCamTexture.Play();
    }
    //call onClick btn (back - close camera)
    public void StopMyCamera()
    {
        //to stop camera need only this line
        webCamTexture.Stop();
        //----try to clear 
        /*GL.Clear(false, true, Color.clear);
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        rawImage.StopAllCoroutines();*/
        //----
    }
```

[image: Second test]

[image: Try to clean Cache]

Comment: try to run garbage collector when you stop the texture.

Comment: I try with garbage collector GC.Collect(); but no release memory still grow up

Comment: So that doesn't work here. you should keep following your thread on Unity3d forum and may report it as a bug.

Comment: I don't think this is a bug. jijie thanks for putting code this time. I tried this on my windows and there was no problem. I do think you are doing something wrong. Can you show the complete code of how you are starting and stopping the camera?

Comment: sorry, I update my post @Programmer .

Comment: @Programmer do you try to put on your phone. ? Please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

Currently you play the video with:

```
var webCamTexture = new WebCamTexture();
rawImage.material.mainTexture = webCamTexture;
webCamTexture.Play();
```

and stop it with

```
webCameraTexture.Stop();
```

This is doing exactly what your code is telling it to do. The `new WebCamTexture()` line of code is expected to allocate memory each time it is called. You are suppose to do this **only once** in the `Start()` function and then you can `play` and `stop` camera without memory allocation.

```
public RawImage rawImage;
WebCamTexture webCamTexture;

void Start()
{
    intCam(); //Do this once. Only once
}

void intCam()
{
    webCamTexture = new WebCamTexture();
    rawImage.material.mainTexture = webCamTexture;
}

public void StartMyCamera()
{
    webCamTexture.Play();
}

public void StopMyCamera()
{
    //to stop camera need only this line
    webCamTexture.Stop();
}
```

Comment: when I run my application in console appear this Error: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. In inspector RawImage is attached to script.

Comment: This code I posted is working on my side. Double click on the error message from the editor and it will show you which line of code is causing it. Post that line of code. Please make sure you copied this as it is. Make sure that the `intCam()` is called before anything in the `Start()` function. Let me know.

Comment: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
BController.StartMyCamera () (at Assets/BController.cs:41)

At the line 41 in the file: webCamTexture.Play();

Comment: This is not what I asked. If you double click on the error from the console, it should open your script editor and show you what line of code is causing that. Anyways, the problem is that from your `StartMyCamera` function. It is likely that webCamTexture  is not called. Are you sure about this? This should be called from the `Start` function. Please move `intCam()` into the `Awake()` function and let me know what happens. If this is not working, where are you calling `StartMyCamera` from?  I want to see what your new code looks like. Please post it here http://pastebin.com/

Comment: I move intCam() into Awake() and works. StartMyCamera() call in first view, onClick NextButton to show second view and start camera. But I do this: next and back 9 times and my app stop.

Comment: think that `StartMyCamera()` as being called before the `intCam()` function. By the way, I was typing fast in my answer. `intCam()` should be `initCam()`. That shouldn't change anything. Is your problem solved now?

Comment: Ok. You wanna remove important things from your project then share it with me? When I have time I will look at it and report back to you. Otherwise, I don't have this problem on side and don't know what could be the problem till I see the rest of the things in script. Edit: You don't have to accept this question if your problem is not actually solved.

Comment: can you send me your unity demo project where you try to open camera?

Comment: It is the code in my answer with two Buttons(Play and Stop) and one RawImage. That's it. Is that the only thing in your code ?

Comment: in my project I have 2 view ( 2 panel (gameobject)) A have a button who open B where start camera (rawImage and button (back)) . When go from A to B and B to A many times my application exit

Comment: Believe me I think there is a problem with how you switch your stuff. If I can't see that I don't know of any other way to help.

Comment: so can we discuss on skype?

Comment: I don't use skype or contact users out of this website. If you have any confidential stuff such as images, audio.... Make a copy of your project or duplicate it,  delete those images or sound and replace them with plain white image then upload. Simply remove stuff that is confidential then test it to make sure that the problem is still there before uploading. I am not forcing you to do this. That's up to you.

Comment: Upload to any website such Google drive then provide link here.

Comment: what phone you have with Windows? Model?

Comment: Ok. Will try it when I get to my phone. Will take time. I use Lumia 640. What Unity full version and phone model are using?

Comment: Unity 5.4 and phone Lumia 650. try like that: next open camera back: camera will close ( repeat many times) if get some error make a screenshot and show me please, thanks for help and tips

Comment: I am sorry for the late reply. I had problems building for Windows phone this weekend. I got some SDK error. I decided I will re-install my OS today and let you know of the test

Comment: ok. I try to clean cache and use garbage collector, and still memory is up, like in third picture. "  Caching.CleanCache();        GC.Collect();"

Answer (score 2):

"Resources.UnloadUnusedAssets()" is helpful for your problem.

```
public void StopMyCamera()
{
webCamTexture.Stop();
Resources.UnloadUnusedAssets();
}
```